# Can't edit a file in Eclipse after clicking "No" in a popup warning about it being derived

Tags: eclipse, derived

I created, as I was instructed by a more senior developer, a new .sql file in Eclipse in a project folder buried somewhere in the entire application's overall project structure. When I tried to edit the file, Eclipse asked me whether I'm sure if I want to edit a derived file. I clicked "No" arbitrarily to make the popup go away and to be able to check the file's and project's properties just to be sure, because as far as I knew, the files in the project were not actually derived from anything.

Problem is, the file is now apparently locked for editing, and I don't see any way of unlocking it. In the properties, it is not marked as Read-only, nor is it in fact marked as Derived.

How do enable editing on this file again?

Comment: The _derived_ flag is to exclude files e. g. from search and version control (e. g. files of the `bin/` folder). [By default a warning is shown, if you want to edit a derived file](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-texteditorprefs.htm). If you clicked _No_, just close and reopen the file. If this does not help, check if the file is locked by another application or process (e. g. by open it with a text editor outside of Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I deleted the file and created a new one with the same name, which is tedious, but it fixed the problem. I did not try closing and opening it again as howlger suggested, though that might have worked as well.